# Thread-Safe Access Counter

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement Thread Safe Access Counter. What I need to do is create a HashMap which contains the path and integer(Counter). It has two methods which checks whether the map contains the path or not and accordingly increases the count if the path occurs as shown below

```
public class AccessCounter {
private HashMap<Integer,java.nio.file.Path> counter= new HashMap<Integer,java.nio.file.Path>();
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();  
private Path path ;
private RequestHandler rq; 

public void map(HashMap<Integer,java.nio.file.Path> counter){ 
    counter.put(10,Paths.get("/Users/a.html"));
    counter.put(5, Paths.get("b.html")); 
    counter.put(2, Paths.get("c.txt"));
    counter.put(7, Paths.get("d.txt")); 
}

public void increment(){ 
    lock.lock(); 
    System.out.println("Lock Obtained");
    try{ 
        if(counter.keySet().equals(rq.fileName())){
            for(Integer key: counter.keySet()){
                Path text = counter.get(key);   
                key++;
            }
        }
        else { 
            counter.put(1,path);
        }
    }finally{
        lock.unlock();
        System.out.println("Lock released");
    }
}

public void getCount(){ 
    lock.lock(); 
    System.out.println("Lock Obtained");
    try{ 
        if(counter.keySet().equals(rq.fileName())){
            for(Integer key: counter.keySet()){
                Path text = counter.get(key);   
                key++;
            }
        }
        else { 
            return ;
        }
    }finally{
        lock.unlock();
        System.out.println("Lock released");
    }
}
```

}

RequestHandler(Runnable Class) -> Run() -> picks up one of the files and calls increment method and getCount(). In main method I have to create multiple thread s to AccessCounter concurrently. Could anyone suggest me the right direction. I am doing something wrong but havent able to find it.

```
public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {
private AccessCounter ac;
private File file;

public void select(File file) {
    File file1 = new File("a.html");
    File file2 = new File("b.html");
    File file3 = new File("a.txt");
}

public File fileName() {
    return file;
}

public void run() {
    select(file);
    ac.increment();
    ac.getCount();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new RequestHandler());
    thread1.start();
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new RequestHandler());
    thread2.start();
}
```

}

Comment: I think want you map to be `HashMap<java.nio.file.Path, Integer>` instead of `HashMap<Integer,java.nio.file.Path>` as you intend to have the count of number of entries with same `Path`. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I need to do. Ill fix that. Thanks

Comment: On the similar lines, any reason why you not want to use `ConcurrentHashMap<Path, AtomicInteger>` instead. This has `putIfAbsent` method that does it atomically and `AtomicInteger` can increment atomically using `incrementAndGet` method without any lock/synchronization in the user code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a ConcurrentHashMap and a AtomicLong is all you need for thread safety and simplicity.

```
final ConcurrentMap<Path, AtomicLong> counterMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void incrementFor(Path path) {
    counterMap.computeIfAbsent(path, p -> new AtomicLong()).incrementAndGet();
}

public long getCount(Path path) {
    AtomicLong l = counterMap.get(path);
    return l == null ? 0 : l.get();
}
```

computeIfAbsent will place a new AtomicLong as required in a thread safe manner.

Note: as ConcurrentMap supports concurrent access, you can have many thread using this Map at the same time (provided they are accessing a different Path)

Comment: This looks much simpler and better. +1

Comment: Thanks guys! Really helpful

Answer (score 1):

> private HashMap counter= new
>   HashMap();

Instead of `HashMap<Integer,java.nio.file.Path>` you need to have `HashMap<java.nio.file.Path, Integer>`, as your intend is to have the count of number of entries with same Path.

A good optimization I see, unless you want to try with normal `HashMap` and `lock` in the user code:

You can use `ConcurrentHashMap<Path, AtomicInteger>` instead of `HashMap<..>` above.

`ConcurrentHashMap` has a `putIfAbsent(...)` method that performs it atomically in a single statement.

`AtomicInteger` allows us to increment atomically using `incrementAndGet` method.

Both without extra locks/synchronization in the user code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! Definitely would make changes. For now do you see any mistakes in the code because I am unable to run it

Comment: @Azib.H I see couple of changes are needed. `ac` in the `RequestHandler` is not initialized. And you need to make sure both the threads are using the same `ac` else each `ac` will have its own `HashMap`. And I don't see where you are calling `map(...)` method of `ac`. Even in the `select(...)` method of `RequestHandler` you are creating three `File` instances but not being used anywhere. Finally, update your question with latest code.